# Meaning of "Just for the academics of it"

Tags: expressions

my question is in the title :) thank you in advance for considering answering me.

I wish you a happy new year !

Comment: Need some more details.  What is the context of this. Who said it. To whom did they say it? What were they talking about? Please provide as much detail as possible.

Comment: From the full (subscription-only) OED: [***academic***](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/880?redirectedFrom=academic#eid) - *U.S., Canadian, and Indian English. **In plural.** Reading, thinking, and study as opposed to technical or practical work.* But as a Brit, I don't recognise the usage - I'd say something like *Just out of [academic] **curiosity**.*

Comment: Note that Google finds half-a-dozen instances of *just for the academics of it* on the Internet at large, but that sequence doesn't occur at all in Google Books. On the other hand there are many hundreds if not thousands of written instances of [*just out of academic curiosity*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22just+out+of+academic+curiosity%22), and far more of [*just out of curiosity*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22just+out+of+curiosity%22), so that's the way to go if you want *everyone* to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The speaker is saying that there aren't a lot of reasons to do something, but someone should do it anyway, just because it will have benefits that are academic in nature.  Academia is the world of higher education, so maybe it will help someone who is a student.

Perhaps the speaker is not talking about college and universities, etc., though - he might be just using a colorful word, more or less, meaning that what he is about to do will be a good experiment and something might be learned by it.

As someone points out, it is poor usage.  Informal.  It might be said jokingly, or to seem nonchalant.